# Recursion and returning values in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've recently been practicing writing recursive functions in JavaScript, and I've been running into a problem consistently when it comes to return values, which is that they ALWAYS seem to be undefined when returned from inside a conditional block.

Here is an example on jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/g0dm68nm/

This is a simple binary sort implemented recursively. At this block of code

```
if (array[guess] === targetValue){
    console.log("equal");
    return(guess);
}
```

I see in my console "equal", which would never happen unless

```
    A) The variable guess is defined
    B) The item located at the index of that array equals the target search value
```

So I know that guess is absolutely defined or else my function would never evaluate the console.log statement, but the value returned is always undefined.

What am I missing? What is it that I am not understanding about recursion? This is the third function in the last 2 weeks I've written that behaves in the same way and I can't find any sort of answer anywhere online.

Comment: For this operation you don't need to use slice. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the call to the recursive function otherwise the values don't get passed on. For example:

```
// Added: return doSearch(array, targetValue);

let doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    let min = 0;
    let max = array.length - 1;
    let guess = Math.floor((max + min) / 2);

    if (array[guess] === targetValue) {
        console.log("equal");
        return guess;
    } else if (array[guess] > targetValue) {
        array = array.slice(0, guess);
        return doSearch(array, targetValue);
    } else if (array[guess] < targetValue) {
        array = array.slice(guess + 1);
        return doSearch(array, targetValue);
    } else {
        return "not in the list";
    }
};
```

Also, I suspect you want to return `return array[guess]` in the final return, which should give the number. By the time you've split the array on each recursion, the value of `guess` will be less than meaningful.

Comment: I remember trying to do this and get an error that my function wasn't defined, but I just tried it and it work perfectly so I must have made a typo. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `return`. And probably change your code to keep track of min and max if you want the original index:

```
let doSearch = function(array, minI, maxI, targetValue) {
    let guess = Math.floor((maxI + minI)/2);
    if(array[guess] === targetValue) {
      console.log("equal");
      return guess;
    } else if (minI === maxI) {
      console.log("Not in list")
      return
    } else if (array[guess] > targetValue) {
      return doSearch(array, minI, guess, targetValue);
    } else if (array[guess] < targetValue) {
      return doSearch(array, guess+1, maxI, targetValue);
    }
};

let primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
        41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

let result = doSearch(primes, 0, primes.length-1, 71);
```

Comment: I agree that using `slice` is pretty bad, so I commend you for removing those calls.  I just think the code would look nicer with a simpler function signature like before.  Maybe use a nested function for the actual search implementation and have the outer function act as a wrapper that calls it with the initial arguments?

Comment: Totally agree with this!

Comment: @kamoroso94 I was using slice because the massive function calls and all the variable assignments looked ridiculous. It's a lot more concise and attractive with slice in place. I like your compromise though, I will give that a try!

Comment: You could move `min` and `max` to the end of the signature and set them to the default values if nothing is passes.  (i.e. `minI = typeof min === 'undefined' ? 0 : min` `maxI = typeof max === 'undefined' ? primes.length-1 : max` ) Then you could call the function with just the array and guess.

Comment: @Mark_M Is there a reason you're using a ternary operator for the default parameters instead of just the default value?

Comment: @kamoroso94 yes.  You don't want to set the default value with every recursion. On recursion you want to use the values passed in the arguments. You only want default values the first time when no arguments are passed.

Comment: @Mark_M Yes, that's the behavior of default parameters.  The default values only get applied when no argument is provided.  If one is, it will use it instead of the default.  Check out the article on MDN on [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Comment: Oh, @kamoroso94- I misunderstood your question. Sure that works too.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple `return` statements.  When you do a recursive call that gives you a value back, you need to do something with that value; in this case, return it.  That is why you were getting `undefined`.  The code was doing exactly what you asked, finding the item, but never passing it back up the call stack.

**Edit:** Secondly, (I missed this), since you are slicing up the array, the index of the solution in the sliced array isn't necessarily the same as that in the source array, so you should adjust for that when it gets shifted.

**Edit 2:** I would suggest using a common sentinel value like `-1` rather than the string you're using when the value is not in the array.

```js
let doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    let min = 0;
    let max = array.length - 1;
    let guess = Math.floor((max + min)/2);

    if(array[guess] === targetValue) {
      console.log("equal");
      return guess;
    } else if (array[guess] > targetValue) {
      array = array.slice(0, guess);
      return doSearch(array, targetValue);
    } else if (array[guess] < targetValue){
      array = array.slice(guess + 1);
      return doSearch(array, targetValue) + guess + 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: I would not use slice at all. Please see my answer.